# Integrate PHP website with Wordpress user authentication

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, authentication

I have an existing Wordpress website that requires users to login if they want to access additional content (full stories, archive of past stories, etc).

I've built a new website using PHP and MySQL that will is hosted on a different server. This website is intended for the same audience who visit the article website mentioned previously.

The new website will provide access to database content that is not publicly available and I would like to authenticate visitors using the login details already used by the Wordpress website.

Are there API calls that would allow authentication against the Wordpress user accounts from the other server using PHP?

Comment: The method described here should work well for you.

http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/26457/how-to-use-wordpress-authentication-on-non-wordpress-page

Answer (score 2):

you can authenticate them using: 
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_signon