# login to wordpress in custom php page

Tags: php, wordpress

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Integrate PHP website with Wordpress user authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13792576/integrate-php-website-with-wordpress-user-authentication)

I am trying to perform a login outside wordpress install directory via a php script. I want to use the same users and users state on the whole website, not just the blog.

So far I managed to verify the credentials by including 'class-phpass.php', but I haven't found anything about performing the actual login.

Is there any way to create the cookies and use them in wordpress and viceversa?

I also found a plugin that makes my cookies available for the whole domain, so I think I'm very close.

Comment: Hm, depends on how dirty their bootstrap is. It seems to be a case of including 'wp-load.php' & running `wp_signon($credentials)`... But I've never worked with Wordpress and a glance at their code does not make me confident this can work without bootstrapping side effects....

Comment: @Oldskool tried that already, but as soon as I included user.php, it required another page and so on, which I don't think it's right.

Comment: @Wrikken Includin wp-load.php gave me a 'headers already sent' error.. but still I think it's a better start than using user.php

Comment: whoops! my bad. I had a space before the php tag.. so that's why I had that error. The example from here http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_signon combined with the proper include page was a go! thanks @Wrikken! you can write the answer if you want so I can accept it :)